# Are there consequences of not taking the return leg of a Stockholm-Tallinn day cruise with Tallink Silja Line?

Tags: ferries

Three friends and I want to do Stockholm -> Tallinn -> Helsinki -> Stockholm for a three-day weekend in January (leaving on the 13th, coming back on the 16th). The original plan is :

- Stockholm -> Tallinn on a **Tallink-Silja Line** ferry
- Tallinn -> Helsinki also on a **Tallink-Silja Line** ferry
- Helsinki -> Stockholm by plane.

Now the thing is that Tallink-Silja Line offers *day cruises* (leaving Stockholm on the 13th, arriving in Tallinn on the 14th during the morning and leave on the 14th in the evening back to Stockholm) whose tickets are much cheaper than standard one-way tickets. For four people and the dates I provided above, a day cruise is 78€ and a regular one-way ticket is 159€ (same as a return ticket that's not on a day cruise, me thinks).

Of course, I am fully aware that we will lose the return leg of the day cruise if we choose to book the day cruise and only do the Stockholm -> Tallinn leg, and it's not a problem at all. I'm simply trying to find out if there is more to it. The Terms of Use don't really mention the issue.

**Could there be consequences in buying the cheap return day cruise tickets and not taking the return leg of the journey?**

I know this question has been asked multiple times on TSE and with different carriers, but please take into consideration the fact that I also want to use Tallink - Silja Line for the second leg of the journey (Tallinn -> Helsinki): I wouldn't want to be on some sort of a blacklist or anything.

Comment: When booking your tickets, make a tiny mistake in your names (e.g. put an a instead of o). You'd be allowed on board, but the automatic booking systems would have issues matching up your reservations

Comment: @pnuts, I was able to find some T&C's and other info [here](http://www.tallinksilja.com/en/web/int/travel-terms-and-conditions-for-individuals) and [there](http://www.tallinksilja.com/en/web/int/good-to-know). Thanks for your insight! I'm indeed particularly interested to know if that can give them grounds not to sell us tickets for the second leg of the journey (and for further trips).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did that on Helsinki-Tallinn route, and there were no consequences.

Note there is also a Viking/Eckero line serving this route, so if you are really worried about this affecting your other reservations on Sulja, you can book those (i.e. book Sulja from Stockholm, and book Viking from Tallinn). They're all priced similarly.

Comment: Yes, as I returned on another round trip leg, booked separately a few days later. Regarding booking, AFAIR they only ask your first/last name when booking (and contact info), so I wonder how would they even check this during the reservation?

Answer (score 5):

I've done this numerous times, and never had any issues. Then again, I always check in at the check-in kiosk rather than seeing an agent at a desk, who will require ID.

If checking in at a desk, it is possible (I don't know for sure) that they might detect your "cheating" and impose heavy fines, as this kind of fare-cutting is officially not allowed. However, if using a kiosk, there is absolutely no way to get caught.

So, use a check-in kiosk always and you will be 100% fine

Comment: They cannot impose any fine (generally only a court or government agency can impose a fine). Even if they file a lawsuit against you, I don't see how they can win anything because the contract does not  specify any monetary damages which are paid to the carrier if you skip the return leg. Thus I don't see any basis of a claim for damages, nor a way to justify them.