# Ferry from Helsinki to Tallinn

Tags: ferries, helsinki, tallinn

I'm planning to travel from Helsinki to Tallinn in late April 2019. I already research that only 3 companies do that route (Tallink Silja Line, Viking Line and Eckero Line).

I would like to know if is worth it to book the ferry online (in terms of price or time spared).  In case it's relevant i'm planning on travel on a Saturday or Sunday, probably on the afternoon ferry.

Comment: Are you bringing a car? If not, Linda Line offers a faster option from the city center of Helsinki to Tallinn, and back in 2012 they were even cheaper than the ferries. However, they are currently not running and don't say when they will be back, so there's no guarantee that they will be running by the time you want to travel :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk-up fares will generally be expensive (and almost never cheaper) than booking online, so as long as your schedule is fixed, I would **recommend booking ahead**.

Also check out **day cruise fares**: odd as it may seem, it can be much cheaper to book a return fare, which are often steeply discounted, than a one-way fare, which usually are not.  For example, at time of writing [Tallink is offering cruises for €12](https://www.tallinksilja.fi/paras-hinta#firstTabs-content-1), whereas same-day walk-up fares are €31-41.  And yes, [it's fine to throw away the return](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84565/are-there-consequences-of-not-taking-the-return-leg-of-a-stockholm-tallinn-day-c?rq=1).